# Bluetooth Low Energy advertising to be discoverable in iOS Settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS app which is using CBPeripheralManager to implement a peripheral.
I start advertising with the command:

```
 [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : @"MY_DEVICE_NAME"}];
```

According to the Apple docuentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheralManager/startAdvertising:

> only two of the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey and CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey

My issue is that I want this peripheral to be discoverable in the Settings -> Bluetooth area of iOS settings. 
At present it is only discoverable via an app and the CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices API call.
Do I need to add a data service to make it discoverable via iOS settings ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bluetooth Low Energy devices are not discoverable in the Settings->Bluetooth page.  This is only for Bluetooth 2.1/3.0 devices such as keyboards and headsets/handsfree devices.

A Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral is only discoverable by an app using Core Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, any idea where this is documented ?

Comment: I don't know where it is documented, but it is logical - iOS can't do anything with BLE GATT peripherals natively - you need an app that can work with the peripheral.  Why do you want your peripheral discoverable in the settings app?

Comment: We have a BLE device that solicits for ANCS, as such is is visible in iOS settings. But we also want to connect to it via a service. At present this makes the UseEx awkward as some pairing is done in-app and some in iOS settings. We want all pairing to be done in one or the other, ideally for simplicity not in the custom app.

Comment: Even if it was paired in settings, you would need to discover and select a peripheral in your app via some UI - otherwise how would you know which peripheral the user wanted

Comment: Because the device has a custom service UUID. 1) User connects via settings then 2) user runs app which retrieves that device by looking for device with that service. Sure if the user connects to 2 identical devices in settings then he can't differentiate between them. But then the 'Help' instructions would explain to the user that is a bad idea and that only one device per iPhone is allowed.

Comment: Well, as far as I know there is no way to initiate pairing with a BLE device from settings.