# Can iOS Bluetooth find BLE Devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

Can iOS Settings -> Bluetooth menu discover and pair with third-party Bluetooth Low Energy devices, and if so what kind criteria do they have to meet in order to be listed there?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple support](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71627) it is not possible to see BLE devices listed on the Bluetooth Settings page. Only Bluetooth 2.1/3.0 devices are listed such as keyboards and headsets ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211573/bluetooth-low-energy-advertising-to-be-discoverable-in-ios-settings)). For BLE devices you must use the device's own app or any other 3rd party app which uses CoreBluetooth.